# Execute plsql script (having IN and OUT parameters) from a .sql file using MyBatis with annotations

Tags: plsql, annotations, mybatis

I am using **MyBatis with annotations**.

It is possible to execute anonymous block of plsql script using mybatis if we put the script inside @Update() annotation.

But I am looking for a way to have the **anonymous block** of plsql script loaded from a **separate .sql file**. This will avoid the formatting issues(plusses and quotes and spaces and all that) every time I have to update the script. Also helps with version control in GIT.

Also, the plsql script has a few **IN and OUT parameters**.

After some googling, I have found that ScriptRunner can be used to execute sql script files. But, I am not sure if I can have parameters there.

Comment: if you need to overcome formatting issues, you can use a Mapper XML file where you can write the procedure call or the query.

Comment: It is an anonymous block, not procedure. The script file if kept separately, will help with version control in repository. Also someone who works on the script does not have to touch our MyBatis Config. And I am looking for a way to do it using annotations if possible.